# Python 3: Thread: Killing callable execution after Aborted due to Timeout?

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, timeout, kill

Can the underlying execution of a thread be killed after it has bee aborted due to timeout?

I am following the following threading approach provided here:
[Timeout a Python Callable](https://meitham.com/2012/12/15/timeout-a-python-callable/)

A revised version of this code for Python 3 is below.

This code does properly timeout of a callable function by throwing a `RuntimeError` when implemented `threading.Thread.abort()` is called, which is as expected when it was assigned timeout value to `threading.Thread.join(timeout)`.

However, even though the thread was aborted, the underlying callable is still executing.

**Question**: How can I kill this thread after it has been aborted to stop the underlying callable from continuing to execute, without killing the parent executable?

Here is my code:

```
import datetime as dt
import threading

def run_command_with_threaded_timeout(
    func,
    fargs=None,
    fkwargs=None,
    threaded_run_timeout_secs=None
):
    class TimedThread(threading.Thread):
        """An abortable thread, by raising an exception inside its
        context.
        """

        def __init__(self):
            super(TimedThread, self).__init__()
            self.exc_info = (None, None, None)

        def run(self):
            self.started_at = dt.datetime.now()
            try:
                args = fargs if fargs else list()
                kwargs = fkwargs if fkwargs else dict()
                request_func = partial(func, *args, **kwargs)
                self.result = request_func()
            except:
                # save the exception as an object attribute
                self.exc_info = sys.exc_info()
                self.result = None

            self.ended_at = dt.datetime.now()

        def abort(self):
            self.ended_at = dt.datetime.now()
            threaded_run_diff = self.ended_at - self.started_at
            threaded_run_diff_secs = threaded_run_diff.seconds                
            if threaded_run_diff_secs >= threaded_run_timeout_secs:
                raise RuntimeError(
                    "Threaded Run: Timed Out"
                    )

            raise RuntimeError(
                "Threaded Run: Aborted"
            )

    t = TimedThread()
    t.start()
    t.join(timeout=threaded_run_timeout_secs)
    if t.exc_info[0] is not None:  # if there were any exceptions
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = t.exc_info
        # Raise the exception/traceback inside the caller
        raise exc_type.with_traceback(exc_value, exc_traceback)

    if t.is_alive():
        t.abort()
        diff = t.ended_at - t.started_at            
        raise RuntimeError("%(f)s timed out after %(d)r seconds" %
                           {'f': func, 'd': diff.seconds})

    return t.result
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I have read is that a thread cannot be killed from the outside.

What can be done is to provide a global that is read by thread to determine if it is still alive.

```
global is_alive = True
kwargs = {
    'config_job': config_job,
    'config_request_params': config_request_params,
    'config_request_credentials': config_request_credentials,
    'config_request_retry': config_request_retry
}

try:
    response = run_command_with_threaded_timeout(
        func=cmd,
        fargs=None,
        fkwargs=kwargs,
        timeout_sec=timeout_sec
    )
except Exception as ex:
    is_alive = False
    raise
```

Comment: Even though this is rather old, It keeps popping up on searches.
The use of 'global' should generally be avoided. Especially for passing information between threads (and processes). Consider using an Event instead